# Error is missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table empl 
(
     empid number primary key,
     empname varchar(25),
     email varchar(25) not null unique,
     doj date not null,
     sal number not null check (sal > 0),
     deptid number FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dept(deptid) 
);
```

Comment: there should be a little bit of context and an actual question. Like this the post means nothing.

Comment: @NicolaMiotto . . . I actually found the question understandable.  Too succinct, but quite understandable.  The error message is in the title and the code is the question.  A little text like:  "I run this statement and get such-and-such error message.  How can I fix it?" would make the question better.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `FOREIGN KEY`:

```
create table empl (
    empid number primary key,
    empname varchar(25),
    email varchar(25) not null unique,
    doj date not null,
    sal number not null check (sal>0),
    deptid number REFERENCES dept(deptid)
);
```

SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b4b2).

When defining a column, the foreign key relationship is established by the keyword `references`.  You use `foreign key` when you want to introduce it as a constraint *after* the columns are defined.  So you could also write:

```
create table empl (
    empid number primary key,
    empname varchar(25),
    email varchar(25) not null unique,
    doj date not null,
    sal number not null check (sal>0),
    deptid number,
    foreign key (deptid) REFERENCES dept(deptid)
);
```

By the way, when using Oracle, one usually uses `varchar2()` instead of `varchar()`.

Comment: What might be worth mentioning is that this depends on the database system. Microsoft SQL Server does allow `FOREIGN KEY` even for column constraints.